# Need to make design in react-native bottom navigator as below image

Tags: react-native, styles, bottomnavigationview, radius

I want a UI simillar to the image in which corners above a view should be rounded in as shown in as image.

[image: Make design with this corner squared in image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should achieve your desired result, just replace the `div:before` block with the item at the top in your screenshot if it is an image. If no image use `div:before` changing the color is `box-shadow`.

```
div {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #522d5b;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  left:0;
  height:40px;
  width:300px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below style and the image will be the same as per your requirement

- borderBottomLeftRadius: number
- borderBottomRightRadius: number

Below is the code sample you can refer to.

```
image: {
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
  borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
}
```

one more solution is there

```
borderRadius:0,0,20,0;
```

Also, you can find more info in the [view component docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view.html).